# SSH X11 Forwarding XInputExtension missing

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, x11forwarding

When trying to open a GUI-program on a SSH-Session with X11-Forwarding (both client and server have X11Forwarding activated) I get this error:

Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":4".
Application asked to unregister timer 0x8000003 which is not registered in this thread. Fix application.

VNC to this server is working correctly.

OS: Ubuntu Server

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
ssh -Y
```

to connect to the box as explained in [this post](http://scotgate.org/2007/11/28/missing-xinputextension-when-using-xforwarding-over-ssh/)

Comment: I'm still getting this error: Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display

Comment: Seems like something has changed.
The RANDR extension could be needed if the app needs to go full screen. Try launching it in a window if you can.
Alternatively you could use standard X Display configuration with those commands:
`xhost +`
`ssh remotebox`
`export DISPLAY=local.box.ip.address:0`
`gui-program`
After making sure your X server is listening on a TCP port (don't remember which file under /etc/ controls this, though)

Comment: after installing libxrandr2 ssh -Y worked